# Strange df output after ddrescue clone

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, dd, disk, ddrescue

My old harddisk was having I/O error last week so I tried to copy the data out to another new disk intending to rescue the data. I use `ddrescue`:

```
ddrescue -f /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 my_mapfile
```

After I use `ddrescue` to clone the whole partition from old to new disk (it already partitioned upfront), I able to save my data and I am able to mount it and read my data in the new drive without problem.

Now the strange thing is when I do a `df`, I have such output:

```
Filesystem                          1K-blocks                Used             Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1                64735862822350640424 1444576192909379016 -10495689665396945056    - /mnt/new_partition
```

If I do a ''df -hT'', I got this:

```
Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1                jfs        56Z  2.0Z   -9Z    - /mnt/new_partition
```

Both the old and new partition is 2TB.

Anybody know why I can't get the 'Use%' output and why there is a 'Z' symbol there and negative 'Avail' reading ?

I didn't do any other tuning after done the `ddrescue` cloning though.

Comment: Z = Zettabyte.  Figures are abnormal due to some sort of metadata corruption.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettabyte

Comment: @steve: metadata corruption ? where is that metadata located and how to fix that ? I did guest it might be Zettabyte but my hddisk is only 2TB. Do you have any same experience before ?